# Calculate metric tensor, inverse metric tensor, and Cristoffel symbols for Earth's surface

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor

From 'General Relativity Theoretical Minimum' chapter 3 Exercise 3.

Typically this series is very good and I use it to look beyond the first year of university, but for the metric tensor, this series did an appallingly bad job of explaining it- I didn't realise it was going to be this bad and difficult to understand, and I suspect that is because the book has pages upon pages of plain text with almost no equations and examples, unlike literally all other volumes of the series.

Question 1: On Earth, with the polar coordinates $\theta$ and $\phi$, find the metric tensor $g_{\mu\nu}$.
Already I am stuck because I do not know how to find the metric tensor- I do not know a formula that does it.
I know that the distance is

$$dS^2= R^2(d\theta)^2+ R^2\cos^2\theta (d\phi)^2$$

But have no clue on how to get that into a metric form. I need it in a matrix form. Funny thing is, if I see the metric tensor for a sphere in matrix form I will be able to do the entire question in less than a minute. As such, I am completely stuck.

Answer (score 8):

> I know that the distance is
> $$dS^2= R^2(d\theta)^2+ R^2\cos^2\theta (d\phi)^2$$
> But have no clue on how to get that into a metric form.
> I need it in a matrix form.

It is simpler than you think.
You can rewrite this in matrix form as
$$dS^2= \begin{pmatrix} d\theta & d\phi \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} R^2 & 0 \\ 0 & R^2\cos^2\theta \end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} d\theta \\ d\phi \end{pmatrix}.$$
Notice the zeros because there is no $d\theta\ d\phi$
or $d\phi\ d\theta$ term in your given $dS^2$.

The matrix in the middle are the metric components:
$$\begin{pmatrix} g_{\theta\theta} & g_{\theta\phi} \\ g_{\phi\theta} & g_{\phi\phi} \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 6):

Easy! For any metric $g_{\mu\nu}$, the line element is defined as
$$ds^2 = g_{\mu\nu} dx^\mu dx^\nu$$
On a 2-sphere, we only have 2 coordinates, so $\mu$ and $\nu$ can take the values 1 and 2. i.e. $dx^1= d\theta$, $dx^2 = d\phi$
Thus, following the Einstein summation convention:
$$ds^2 = g_{11} d\theta^2 + g_{12} d\theta d\phi + g_{21} d\phi d\theta + g_{22} d\phi^2$$
Now, compare this to the line element you wrote in your question. We find:
$$g_{12} = g_{21} = 0$$
$$g_{11} = R^2$$
$$g_{22} = R^2 \cos^2(\theta)$$
Thus, written as a matrix,
$$g_{\mu\nu} = \begin{pmatrix}
R^2 & 0\\
0 & R^2 \cos^2(\theta)
\end{pmatrix}$$